# How to get voronoi edge diagram in python

Tags: python, voronoi

I want to create a voronoi edge diagram for dot annotations (binary image of nuclei positions ). I used the code from [here](https://github.com/huiqu18/WeaklySegPointAnno/blob/master/prepare_data.py) to create voronoi edge diagram but what I get as a result is shown in an image [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y13gb.png). I just need voronoi edges. Following is the code

Voronoi edge diagram

```
def viro(img):
 label_point=img
 h, w = label_point.shape
 points = np.argwhere(label_point>0)
 vor = Voronoi(points)
 regions, vertices = voronoi_finite_polygons_2d(vor)
 box = Polygon([[0, 0], [0, w], [h, w], [h, 0]])
 region_masks = np.zeros((h, w), dtype=np.int16)
 edges = np.zeros((h, w), dtype=np.bool)
 count = 1
 masks= np.zeros((h, w), dtype=np.bool)
 for region in regions:
            polygon = vertices[region]
            # Clipping polygon
            poly = Polygon(polygon)
            poly = poly.intersection(box)
            polygon = np.array([list(p) for p in poly.exterior.coords])
            mask = poly2mask(polygon[:, 0], polygon[:, 1], (h, w))            
            edge = mask * (~morphology.erosion(mask, morphology.disk(1)))
            edges += edge
            region_masks[mask] = count
            count += 1

 # fuse Voronoi edge and dilated points
 label_point_dilated = morphology.dilation(label_point, morphology.disk(1))
 label_vor = np.zeros((h, w, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
 label_vor[:, :, 0] = (edges > 0).astype(np.uint8) * 255
 label_vor[:, :, 1] = (label_point_dilated > 0).astype(np.uint8) * 255

 return label_vor
```

Answer (score 0):

I happen to figure out the issue. Actually the problem was with the binary image as it is a ground truth of nuclei position with 3 pixel radius so instead of getting single coordinate for one nuclei(single pixel), it retrieved three coordinate values because of 3 pixel radius for each nuclei position thus giving the resultant image.